# correlation matrix vs. correlation function?

Tags: autocorrelation, correlation, matrix

Can someone help me understand the difference between a 1-dim autocorrelation *function* and a 2-dim autocorrelation *matrix* of a random process aka time series?

My Leon-Garcia textbook defines CX(τ) and RX(τ) as 1-dim functions, yet Haykin's Adaptive Filter Theory defines what looks like the same thing, but as the correlation *matrix* R instead. I see that the matrix appears to arise when the time series is represented by complex numbers (sinusoids), but is that the only real difference, or is there a fundamental distinction that I'm missing?

And does the correlation *matrix* R reduce to the 1-dim autocorrelation *function* when the time series can be represented by only real numbers instead of complex numbers, i.e. in that case the correlation matrix is unnecessary?

thanks,
js.

Comment: Does this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Relation_to_the_correlation_matrix

Comment: Thanks for responding...but I don't think that helps me...

Comment: Can you add the equations? I don't have access to these textbooks.

Comment: Sure. But first, in general, I believe autocorrelation Rx(τ) can be constructed by just multiplying all the time series values (x1, x2, x3, x4, ...) together like this:
Rx(0) = x1x1 + x2x2 + x3x3 + ...
Rx(1) = x1x2 + x2x3 + x3x4 + ...
Rx(2) = x1x3 + x2x4 + x3x5 + ...

whereas the first three rows of the corresponding autocovariance matrix would be:
Row 1 = x1x1   x1x2   x1x3 ...
Row 2 = x2*x1  x2x2   x2x3 ...
Row 3 = x3*x1  x3*x2 x3x3 ...

In the EE textbooks, assuming RX(τ) = CX(τ) when mean is zero (autocorrelation = autocovariance)

CX(τ) = E[ (X(t) X(t - τ) ]

Comment: Covariance matrix in Haykin is this: R = [u(n) uH(n)], where u(n) is the time series and H is the Hermitian operator (conjugate transpose).

Comment: Now you are calling it covariance matrix instead of correlation matrix. They are both different but related.

Comment: I thought they were the same if the mean is zero - that's what my textbook says. In fact, the Haykin textbook just assumes that the DC level will be filtered out of the signal (time series) so all signals are considered to be zero-mean, so that autocorrelation = autocovariance.


In any case, I don't believe that's fundamental to my question.